# What is convention for local vars that has same meaning as function argument?

Tags: clojure, naming-conventions

What is convention for local vars that has same meaning as function argument?

If I need **local variable** that has as its initial state value of **function argument** (and thus has the **same meaning**), how should I call it?

As artificial example (that, however, demonstrates quite popular construction in Clojure):

```
(defn sum [coll]
  (loop [local-coll coll, result 0]
    (if (empty? local-coll)
       result
       (recur (rest local-coll) (+ (first local-coll) result)))))
```

Here `local-coll` is initialized to the value of `coll` initially, and it also holds this meaning during looping. `local-coll` is definitely not a good name for it, but what is?

In Haskell it is a good style to put quote (`'`) to the end of variable/function name, e.g. `var'`. In Common Lisp sometimes I saw names ending with asterisk (`*`). Clojure has same notation for *function* that duplicate another function meaning but have a bit different semantics (e.g. [list*](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.h...)). But this notation is also frequently used in docstrings to indicate that there may be several items of this type (e.g. `(methodname [args*] body)*` or `(try expr* catch-clause* finally-clause?)`) and thus can confuse when used for local var names.
Java interop also provides things like `defn-`, that is names ending with hyphen (`-`) to indicate private methods in generated classes. So it makes some sense to use hyphen for local (private for a function) variables too (though it seems a bit weird for me).

So, what the way should I go when naming my local variables with the same meaning as function argument?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's fine to shadow the argument name when you don't need the original argument any more:

```
(defn sum [coll]
  (loop [coll coll, result 0]
    (if (empty? coll)
       result
       (recur (rest coll) (+ (first coll) result)))))
```

Other variations that I've seen are:

```
(loop [c colls] ...)
(loop [coll initial-coll] ...)
(loop [foo foo-coll] ...)
(loop [s specs] ...)
```